# Setting state correctly using the State Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently learning React and trying to understand how to update the state correctly in a function component.

I've learned from the "State and Lifecycle" section in the React docs that you should update the state if it's using the previous state like the following:

```
// Correct
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  counter: state.counter + 1
}));
```

instead of

```
// Wrong
this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + 1,
});
```

*Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.* ([Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous))

Now I want to achieve the same with a function component using the State Hook `useState`.
As an example how to update the state in a function component the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#updating-state) has the following code snippet:

```
<button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
  Click me
</button>
```

which is equivalent to the following code in a class component:

```
<button onClick={() => this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })}>
  Click me
</button>
```

But isn't this the "wrong" solution because it relies directly on the state?

Comment: You can go through https://blog.usejournal.com/getting-started-with-react-hooks-f0b5c1e3e0e7, https://dev.to/trentyang/replace-lifecycle-with-hooks-in-react-3d4n. To understand how you can replace your life cycled methods with hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But isn't this the "wrong" solution because it relies directly on the state?

`setState` *merges* the new state into the old one. And does it in a 'piecemeal' fashion e.g. new state can contain a small subset of old state's data. So it's beneficial to have the old state at hand inside the `setState` body and explicitly merge it using
 `this.setState(oldState => ({ ...oldState, someProp: true }) )`
'Explicitly' is better because it shows you don't have illusions about what `setState` will do anyway: merging even if you didn't.

`useState` *replaces* the old state with the new one so the need to have access to oldState is less acute. Even though I wouldn't mind it.

As for `updated asynchronously`, both `setState` and `useState` can batch updates. Although `useState` won't do batching when dealing with pending Promises, as opposed to ready-to-use values like `count + 1` from your sample.

Coming back to `setState`, there is another reason why the flavor `setState(oldState => ({...})` is better. Remember, `setState` always do merging no matter what. Combined with batching, it can lead to the following piece code executed by React if the flavor `setState(newValue)` was used:
`Object.assign(oldState, newValue1, newValue2, newValue3)`
where the values `newValueX` are the batched updates. `Object.assign` ensures that 'last update wins'. If the series of `newValueX` represents successive attempts to increment the same counter then it might not work as expected. Therefore the other flavor of `setState` is better. With `useState` and batching it looks like this kind of danger persists.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like following.

```
import React, { userState } from 'react';


function TestHook() {
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function updateCount() {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }


return <button onClick={handleCount}>{count}</button>
}
```

Check it here. https://codesandbox.io/s/one-with-the-hook-0yig1

You can follow it in my Medium post (https://blog.usejournal.com/getting-started-with-react-hooks-f0b5c1e3e0e7)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my question refers to "correct" state update. In your example you are using the state "count" directly but shouldn't you use the previous value like my example above in a class component?